# Calling Pyenv Python From C#

Tags: c#, python, terminal

I'm trying to run Python from C# via a command line process.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process {
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "/Users/username/.pyenv/shims/python",
        Arguments = cmd+" "+args,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

I derived the FileName from using `which`:

```
username$ which python
/Users/username/.pyenv/shims/python
```

However, running `python --version` from the terminal, and then again through the C# process, yield different results:

```
username$ python -V
Python 2.7.11
```

And C#:

```
Python 2.7.10
```

I understand the base problem - that it's calling another version of Python, probably the base one that came from Apple. But what I don't understand is *why*, because as I understand it I'm telling it to call python from pyenv directly. Is there a way to get C# to use the same python executable I'm using from the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that the `python` shim depends on something else in your environment, and you should probably figure out what it’s eventually running, then call that directly.

According to the [pyenv documentation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), it's probably at:

```
$(pyenv root)/versions/2.7.11/bin/python
```

You might also be able to find out by running the shim with `set -x`, and looking at the command trace:

```
(set -x; python --version)
```

Comment: Thanks Samir! This led me down the correct path: I eventually found the actual binary it was calling, and replaced it with that instead. Looks like something was getting lost in the Process.Start call.